# Problem in a gridview when enable textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm having a problem to detect the enabled state of a TextBox when I change the DataSource after a filter string like in my image -> (https://imgur.com/a/JxTQ8ks)

Without filter I can enable the textbox add a value and I got success adding stock (this tb is used for add stock)
Below, I have my code that fails here ( **if (tb.Enabled)**) even when textbox is enabled

```
    protected void ProductStock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int productID = Convert.ToInt32((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument); /*Pega o id do button que foi clicado*/

        Product product = ProductBLL.GetProductByID(productID);
        //cast the sender back to a button
        LinkButton cb = sender as LinkButton;

        //get the current gridviewrow from the button namingcontainer
        GridViewRow row = cb.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

        //use findcontrol to locate the textbox in that row
        TextBox tb = row.FindControl("tbStockEntry") as TextBox;

        if (tb.Enabled)
        {
            if (tb.Text.Length > 0)
            {

                StockEntry se = new StockEntry();
                se.Product = product;
                se.StockEntryQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(tb.Text);

                if (ProductBLL.StockEntryInsert(se) == 1)
                {
                    cb.Text = GlobalMessages.Saving;
                    stockAddedLabel.Visible = true;
                    stockAddedLabel.Text = GlobalMessages.InsertedStock;
                    Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "1;URL=ProductList.aspx");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                tb.Enabled = false;
                cb.Text = GlobalMessages.StockEntry;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            tb.Enabled = true;
            cb.Text = GlobalMessages.Save;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As this happens after the DataSource of the GridView has been changed... I would guess that the TextBox Enabled property is data-bound to an item in the grid data. If so, then whether the TextBox is enabled or not after the DataSource is changed depends on the new data. Make sure that the data after the DataSource changes is indeed valid and is as you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved. The problem was I didn't use the event click to filter and I called the method to filter in page load. It works to filter but I could not add stock for the product. Thanks anyway!